# How to permanently uninstall Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft

The question's in the title. The official website gives only details [for Windows and Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-microsoft-teams-3b159754-3c26-4952-abe7-57d27f5f4c81).

Comment: Does this work `sudo dpkg -P teams`?

Comment: @Kulfy [This comment](https://askubuntu.com/q/1219523/#comment2051033_1219523) looks very close to an answer to me.

Comment: How did you even get teams to work on Ubuntu 22? For me its always just a white screen when starting the app.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Because the Linux version of the Teams application is supplied as a `.deb` file, the installation is registered in your package manager. Note, however, that as part of the installation process, Microsoft also added a software source (PPA) for Teams. That ensures that you automatically receive updates.

The package is named `teams`. You can see this in the output of the command `dpkg -l *team*`. Remove it using

```
sudo apt remove teams
```

You can remove the added PPA using the "Software & Updates", "Other Software" tab, or using the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:repos/ms-teams
```

Comment: Or easier... use `dpkg -l *team* | grep ii`.

Comment: In my case, the package was teams, therefore the solution was `sudo apt remove teams`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, the command to remove the PPA doesn't work. You can open Software and Updates Application, go to Other Software tab and remove the repos/ms-teams entry manually.

Answer (score 8):

From the site https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/teams => the snap solution worked for me, `apt` and `dpkg` didn't.

`snap remove --purge teams` or `snap remove --purge teams-for-linux`

Comment: Hello. The answer would need to know how it was installed.

Comment: I'm not sure, probably by dpkg .deb

Comment: $ snap remove --purge teams
snap "teams" is not installed
$ sudo apt purge teams
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  teams*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
After this operation, 302 MB disk space will be freed.
https://askubuntu.com/a/310/421929

Answer (score 5):

Solution for this issue, you need to rename the Microsoft Teams folder in config directory under `/home/user`.

Full path `.config/Microsoft/Microsoft Teams`

Answer (score 1):

In an older version of Ubuntu Like mine, I use the following line.

```
sudo rm -r {the directory of where you installed the "team"}
```

It depends on How you install it. If you install from Microsoft Website, `.deb` then it is easily uninstalled with the above line. If you installed using Wine but using the `.exe.` file then you need to do something About the `Wine`

`wine uninstall`

** I used an old version, It might work for you and probably not. Hope this help

Comment: `rm` will delete the files and directories of teams but would not "uninstall" that. It'll still appear as a "ghost" in `apt list --installed` and `dpkg -l`.

Comment: I see. But that works on mine. I genuinely don't know why and how.

Comment: Just install Stacer and it lets you remove anything.

Comment: Another approach to manually delete MS Teams is documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391091/reinstall-ms-teams-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-10/1391092#1391092)

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other answers work for you, then check if you've installed one of the later versions via flatpak.

```
$ flatpak list
Name                    Application ID
...
Microsoft Teams         com.microsoft.Teams
...
```

If this is the case, you can uninstall it with:

```
flatpak uninstall com.microsoft.Teams
```