# Teams version on Ubuntu Software Manager

Tags: package-management, software-installation, deb, microsoft-teams

If I go to the Ubuntu (20.04) software manager, I can find at least 3 versions for Teams: teams-for-linux, Microsoft-Teams-insiders, Microsoft-Teams-Preview.

What is the best or the correct version/way to install Teams on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing are different versions of Teams distributed as Snap package by different packagers. Not sure which one is the best.

Best is a relative term, but probably, the best way to install Teams in Ubuntu is to use the official `.deb` [installer package from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-teams/download-app). That is the only "officially" supported way of installing Teams on Linux.

To install the downloaded `.deb`, double-click it. The Software store will install it and pull in all necessary dependencies. Alternatively, you can install from the terminal with either the commands `sudo apt install <path-to-debfile>`  or `sudo dpkg -i  <path-to-debfile>` .

The Microsoft `deb` installer actually adds a PPA for Teams to your system. That means that Teams automatically will be updated when a new version becomes available.

To remove Teams, [see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1219525/558158).

Comment: When I go to the Microsoft download page, and click on the Ubuntu DEB to make it open with the software installer, the output after download is that the Ubuntu Software app pops out with an error message `installation not possible: not supported`

Comment: Your download failed, or you do not have a 64 bit system or you have a different architecture. Of course,you could also try the command line, which I indicated as an alternative possibility for your perusal.